# How to create columns by numerical intervals from values ​of several columns?

Tags: r, data.table, binning

Create columns by numerical intervals from integer values. 6 intervals (columns) partitioned in 15 from 1 to 90.

The new columns will show the number of occurrences for that interval. All input columns are taken as reference values. Some reference values are NA.

These are the input columns

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
11   20   22   54   73   86
1    32   64   69   NA   NA
```

Expected output

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6  1to15 16to30 31to45 46to60 61to75 76to90
11   20   22   54   73   86      1      2      0      1      1      1
1    32   64   69   NA   NA      1      0      1      0      2      0
```

I've seen some examples using cut() but I can't adapt it to the above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Counting elements in a vector within a certain range, as a sliding window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528926/r-counting-elements-in-a-vector-within-a-certain-range-as-a-sliding-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using using `cut`:

```
tmp <- 
t(apply(
  df, # assume df is your dataframe or matrix
  1, 
  function(x) table(cut(x, seq(1, 91, 15), right = FALSE))
))

cbind(df, tmp)
#  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 [1,16) [16,31) [31,46) [46,61) [61,76) [76,91)
#1   11   20   22   54   73   86      1       2       0       1       1       1
#2    1   32   64   69   NA   NA      1       0       1       0       2       0
```

If you want the columns to be named differently `cut` has a `labels` argument you can modify.

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer, a little longer than @DiceboyT one, but can be useful for some one.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    col1 = c(11L, 1L),
    col2 = c(20L, 32L),
    col3 = c(22L, 64L),
    col4 = c(54L, 69L),
    col5 = c(73L, NA),
    col6 = c(86L, NA)),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**Answer code**

```
librar(tidyverse)

left_join(
  df %>% rowid_to_column("row"),
df %>%
  rowid_to_column("row") %>%
  gather(var, value, -row) %>% 
  mutate(cuts = cut(value, seq(1, 90, by = 15)),
         cuts = str_remove_all(cuts, "[\\(\\]]"),
         cuts = str_replace(cuts, ",", "to"),
         cuts = fct_inorder(cuts)) %>%
  count(row, cuts) %>%
  filter(!is.na(cuts)) %>%
  spread(cuts, n, fill = 0)
)
```